# PostgreSQL: Role cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it - really strange :-(

Tags: postgresql, roles, drop

I have a strange behavior when I try to remove one user within our PG instance (11.10). I have looked at other posts. But, none of them solved my issue.

We have the following user which was previously granted access to one dB

```
# \c my_db
# \ddp+
                                Default access privileges
    Owner     | Schema |   Type   |                  Access privileges
--------------+--------+----------+------------------------------------------------------
 fdovy1a969c6 |        | function |
 fdovy1a969c6 |        | schema   |
 fdovy1a969c6 |        | sequence |
 fdovy1a969c6 |        | table    |
 fdovy1a969c6 |        | type     |
...
```

Prior reaching this state, we run the following

```
# reassign owned by fdovy1a969c6 to other_user;
# ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE fdovy1a969c6 in schema public REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTIONS FROM public;
# ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE fdovy1a969c6 REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS FROM public;
```

If we try to run the drop user we get the following:

```
# drop role fdovy1a969c6;
ERROR:  role "fdovy1a969c6" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  owner of default privileges on new relations belonging to role fdovy1a969c6
owner of default privileges on new schemas belonging to role fdovy1a969c6
owner of default privileges on new functions belonging to role fdovy1a969c6
owner of default privileges on new types belonging to role fdovy1a969c6
owner of default privileges on new sequences belonging to role fdovy1a969c6
```

The question we have is why do we have a kind of empty entry for this user as outcome of the \ddp+ ?

The `drop owned by` command will probably delete this user. But, I do not feel too confident to run this command since it will also delete the owned objects... And I do not fully understand what are the objects it currently owns.

Thanks for any hints
José

Answer (score 0):

You have set default privileges for that user that revoke all permissions on all objects from everybody including the owner.

To undo that, grant the respective default privileges. For example, to get rid of the entry for functions:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE fdovy1a969c6
   GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION TO PUBLIC, fdovy1a969c6;
```

You will have to do something similar for all object types.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue as the OP. I'm trying your solution, but it doesn't fix it. In this case, do you think `drop owned by <role>` is the right solution?

Comment: @Federico Yes, that should help.

Comment: For reference, using `\dpp+` I finally realised that the role I wanted to drop was getting default privileges from another role. Removing those and using `drop owned by <role>` afterwards cleared the dependency.